# Hyperlinks for Markdown in VSCode

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, markdown

I want to change hyperlinks to Markdown Hyperlinks all at once.

For example I have (and more of them)

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59030873/keyboard-shortcut-in-vscode-for-markdown-links
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59030873/keyboard-shortcut-in-vscode-for-markdown-links
```

and want to have:

```
[ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)
[keyboard-shortcut-in-vscode-for-markdown-links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59030873/keyboard-shortcut-in-vscode-for-markdown-links)  
[ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)
[keyboard-shortcut-in-vscode-for-markdown-links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59030873/keyboard-shortcut-in-vscode-for-markdown-links)
```

I already found (for keybindings.json)

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+q b",    // Lines 2 Array Only
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": {
      "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(.+)(\\r?(?=\\S))?/[]($1)/g}",
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'markdown'"
}
```

which does a lot, but maybe anybody can add or give me a possibility to find out myself:

- The link description from the last part of the link or to go through all link descriptions with tab so you can add the description easily
- only change links (if there is any text between the links)

tia

Comment: How many lines of text can there be between links?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think using a snippet will work (or I can't figure it out) because of your requirement to only change links if there is any text following the link. That makes `TM_SELECTED_TEXT` not work.  But it can be done with a find and replace pretty easily.

I wrote an extension [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform) that you can use to save the find/replace for future use.  Example keybinding:

```
{
    "key": "alt+q",                  // whatever keybinding you want
    "command": "findInCurrentFile",
    "args": {
            // "find": "(^https:.+\\/)(.*$)(\r?\n)(?=(?!https:))",   // if single line of text between links
            "find": "(.+\\/)(.*$)(\r?\n)(?=\\s*(?!https:)[\\s\\S]*^https:)",  // if multiple lines of text
            "replace": "[$2]($1$2)$3",
            "restrictFind": "selections"  // if you want to only find within selections
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'markdown'"
}
```

[image: markdown links regex]

I believe that satisfies your requirement that some text (I made it for any amount of lines of intervening text) be between links.  And thus the last link - which may have text after it - but no following link - should not be transformed.

[If there is only ever one line of text between links, the regex could be simplified quite a bit.]